# Are one-to-one related tables good for distributed sql databases?

Tags: sql, performance, join, one-to-one, cockroachdb

Suppose i have a *User* table, and other tables (e.g. *UserSettings*, *UserStatistics*) which have one-to-one relationship with a user.
Since sql databases don't save complex structs in table fields (some allow JSON fields with undefined format), is it ok to just add said tables, allowing to store individual (complex) data for each user? Will it complicate performance by 'joining' more queries?

And in distirbuted databases cases, will it save those (connected) tables randomly in different nodes, making more redundant requests with each other and decreasing efficiency?

Comment: Why do you think you can store complex data in "other" tables when you cannot store complex data in "User" table?

Comment: Not sure i understand the question. Tables store data, and other tables can reference them with relations. I'm simply looking for a way to "reference" the data locally without doing a 'join' rountrip to another table, which can potentially sit on another node and take more performance to get the data. Sort of like a javascript-object or python-dict.

Answer (score 1):

1:1 joins can definitely add overhead, especially in a distributed database. Using a JSON or other schema-less column is one way to avoid that, but there are others.

The simplest approach is a "wide table": instead of creating a new table UserSettings with columns a,b,c, add columns setting_a, setting_b, setting_c to your User table. You can still treat them as separate objects when using an ORM, it'll just need a little extra code.

Some databases (like CockroachDB which you've tagged in your question) let you subdivide a wide table into "column families". This tends to let you get the best of both worlds: the database knows to store rows for the same user on the same node, but also to let them be updated independently.

The main downside of using JSON columns is they're harder to query efficiently--if you want all users with a certain setting, or want to know just one setting for a user, you're going to get at least a minor performance hit if the database has to parse a JSON column to figure that out, or you have to fetch the entire blob and do it in your app. If they're more convenient for other reasons though, you can work around this by adding [inverted indexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) on your JSON columns, or [expression indexes](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/expression-indexes.html) on the specific values you're interested in. Indexes can have a similar cost to 1:1 joins, but you can mitigate that in CockroachDB using by using the [STORING](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v22.1/create-index#store-columns) keyword to tell the DB to write a copy of all the user columns to the index.